# Как исправить скрипт регистрации на PHP (PDO)?

Tags: php, pdo

Скрипт работает некорректно, пропускает всех желающих. Кто знает, в чем проблема и как ее исправить?

```
<php
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db", $user, $pwd);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db-> exec("set names utf8");  
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

/**
* REGISTRATION
**/
// Проверка данных пользователя при его регистрации на сайте
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['reg-submit'])) {
  $errors = array();
  if (trim($data['login']) == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите логин';
  }
  if (($data['email']) == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите e-mail';
  }
    if (($data['password']) == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
  }
}

// Если поля заполнены, в переменные записываем введенное
$login = $data['login'];
$email = $data['email'];
$pass = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Если нет ошибок (т.е. все поля заполнены корректно),
// осуществляем проверку на то, чтобы юзер не зарегался 2 раза с тем же эмейлом
 if (empty($errors)) {

   try {
      $query="SELECT login, email FROM users WHERE email = ' . $db->quote($email) . ' OR login = ' . $db->quote($login) . '";
      $query_res = $db->query($query);
      $count = count($query_res->fetchAll());

       // Если найдены, значит логин/эмайл заняты, не регистрируенм, а выводим ошибку
         if ($count > 0) {
           exit("email или login занят!");    
         } else {
           $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, email, password)
               VALUES (" . $db->quote($login) . ", " . $db->quote($email) . ", " . $db->quote($pass) . ")";
           $db->exec($sql);

           echo '<div class="okreged">Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <a href = "/test/index.php">Перейти на главную</a></div>';
        }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }

 } else {
   echo '<div class="notreged">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: А кого он не должен пропускать? И так `$db-> exec("set names utf8");` не делается в PDO, для этого есть dsn при создании экземпляра класса.

Comment: @Visman, так вообще нигде не надо делать, хоть в ПДО, хоть где. - это не работает с соединением базы. а значит, что можно подменить кодировку соединения и крутить им как хочется.. А вообще странный скрипт... И стоит его полностью переписать